# multiprocessing pool manager namespace EOF error

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

When I use pool.manager.namespace to share a pandas dataframe, and each target function will call .sample(5000) to this dataframe, EOF error occurs.

```
def get_sample(i):
    print("start round {}".format(i))
    sample = sharedData.data.sample(5000, random_state=i)

if __name__=='__main__':
    with mp.Pool(cpu_count(logical=False)) as pool0:
        results = pool0.map(load_data, paths)
        sharedData.data = pd.concat(results, axis=0, copy=False)
        genes = sharedData.data.columns
        pool0.close()
        pool0.join()
        del results

    """sampling"""
    with mp.Pool(cpu_count(logical=True)) as pool:
        print("start sampling, total round = {}".format(1000))
        r = pool.map_async(get_sample, [j for j in range(1000)], error_callback=my_error)
        results2 = r.get()
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

which has traceback:

```
start round 145
round35 returns output
round18 returns output
rount161 returns output
start round 704
start round 720
start round 736
start round 752
start round 768
start round 784
start round 800
start round 816
start round 832
start round 848
start round 864
start round 880
start round 896
start round 912
start round 928
start round 944
start round 960
start round 976
start round 992
from error_callback: 

multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/usc/python/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/usc/python/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "sampling2temp.py", line 38, in get_sample_ys
    sample = sharedData.data.sample(5000, random_state=i)
  File "/usr/usc/python/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 1060, in __getattr__
    return callmethod('__getattribute__', (key,))
  File "/usr/usc/python/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 757, in _callmethod
    kind, result = conn.recv()
  File "/usr/usc/python/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 250, in recv
    buf = self._recv_bytes()
  File "/usr/usc/python/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 407, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
  File "/usr/usc/python/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 383, in _recv
    raise EOFError
EOFError
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampling2temp.py", line 105, in <module>
    results2 = r.get()
  File "/usr/usc/python/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
EOFError
```

It seems like the tasks 704 to 992 doesn't return any outputs at all then the Manager process shut down. So when one of the running task read data from manager.namespace.data, it receive EOF.

By the way, if I change sample(5000) to sample(2500) and change the size of Manager.Namespace.data from 2127096024 bytes to 1738281624 bytes, there's no EOF problem. Is that because each worker use too much memory?

Answer (score 2):

A [multiprocessing.Connection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#connection-objects) receiver throws EOFError if all of the associated sender Connections have been closed.

It looks like multiprocessing.Manager is using multiprocessing.Connection under the hood based on the stack trace. Since it doesn't look like your code is prematurely terminating the manager process, I think that the problem must be that the manager process is [hitting an exception and terminating before you are done with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482115/eoferror-with-multiprocessing-manager). Since reducing the sample size seems to fix the problem, [it's possible the Manager process gets killed off by the OOM killer for using too much memory](https://www.memset.com/docs/additional-information/oom-killer/) - you can check if that was the case by using the command suggested on that linked article:

```
dmesg | egrep -i "killed process"
```

You'd expect to see something like this:

```
host kernel: Out of Memory: Killed process 1234 (python).
```

Comment: Is there any way to prevent mp.connection senders pre close?  I typed the command you suggest, and "[2341706.731495] Killed process 42144 (vasp_std) total-vm:3283172kB, anon-rss:1388368kB, file-rss:10528kB, shmem-rss:0kB" appears.

Comment: Hmm that log line looks like something else unrelated to me. I'm not sure if there is a way to prevent that. Since it's not a python process killed off perhaps it isn't because of OOM killing the process, it might be worth monitoring the memory usage of the processes using `top` and `free -m` while the script is executing to see the state of memory and confirm that is the issue before going further.